# Working with sequences of dates in R

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` with a  column of dates in `POSIXct`. What I'm trying to do is to create a new `logical` column that will show if the dates are in some range. For example, if I have this vector: `"2016-10-16 GMT" "2016-04-30 GMT" "2016-08-04 GMT" "2016-11-07 GMT" "2016-09-06 GMT" "2016-01-11 GMT"` and have a range

```
date_from <- "2016-10-10"
date_to <- "2016-11-20"
```

the new column should be

`TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE`

How do I achieve this behavior? The real dataset is tens of thousands rows long and the only easy way to do this for me would be to cycle through all rows, which is not a good way of doing it i believe.

Comment: Convert also `date_from` and `date_to` to `POSIXct`. Then, you can use the standard `>` and `<` operators.

Comment: You can simply create a new column in your dataset like this: `df$new_colum <- df$date >= as.POSIXct(date_from) & df$date < as.POSIXct(date_to)`

Comment: Will try to do so, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only base R you can do this:

```
as.Date(x) %in% as.Date(date_from):as.Date(date_to)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

**data**

```
x <- c("2016-10-16 GMT","2016-04-30 GMT","2016-08-04 GMT","2016-11-07 GMT","2016-09-06 GMT","2016-01-11 GMT") 
date_from <- "2016-10-10"
date_to <- "2016-11-20"
```

Comment: Great answer! Quick question: why do you use `as.numeric` on the first variable? What can happen if you don't use it?

Comment: It works without it, I'll correct my answer, I knew that `:` coerced the dates to numeric, but didn't know that `%in%` would as well :)

Comment: Cool! Can I have one more quick question? :) How would you do that if you had a `data.frame` with 2 columns displaying `date_from` and `date_to` ranges? Trying to make a function out of your answer, to apply it app-wide if needed.

Comment: so each `date` in the source vector has its own `date_to` and `date_from` ?

Comment: No, check every date from the source vector if it's in range of any pairs of `date_to` and `date_from` from the given `data.frame`

Comment: You could use `Map` : `df <- data.frame(date_from = c("2016-10-10","2016-09-10"),date_to = c("2016-11-20","2016-10-20"))` then `Map(function(from,to){as.Date(x) %in% as.Date(from):as.Date(to)},df$date_from,df$date_to)`

Comment: This is to answer your questions with simple short solutions, but try to work with clean data types, it's better not to have these conversion functions all over the place.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: too bad SO doesn't have private messages - I just wanted to let you know I got it to work that way https://pastebin.com/EtWgFEvZ

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` so you wont need to use <> and `lubridate` functions to easily convert the dates.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

f <- c("2016-10-16 GMT", 
"2016-04-30 GMT", 
"2016-08-04 GMT", 
"2016-11-07 GMT", 
"2016-09-06 GMT", 
"2016-01-11 GMT")

f <- ymd(f)

date_from <- ymd("2016-10-10")
date_to <- ymd("2016-11-20")

f %between% c(date_from, date_to) # From data.table
f %within% interval(date_from, date_to) # From lubridate
```

Comment: This way I need to check every date in a column if it's in range, isn't that too expensive?

Comment: Compared to? If you have other solution we could benchmark so see which is fastest.

Comment: I'm still thinking on it. Trying to do make it work with `filter` from `dplyr` package, but can't figure out how to apply all the `date_from` and `date_to` vectors at once. If will succeed I will check the performance

Comment: if it's 10s of thousands rows as you say it should be quite fast with most solutions, have you tried a method that was too slow already ?

Comment: No, not yet. I'm relatively new to R and trying to get all possible solutions I can :)